# php - check for valid guid

Tags: php, guid

I have a mssql database in which my primary keys are GUIDs. I am working on a web interface for inserting some data. I need a GUID, generated by php. I am using `com_create_guid()` function. So, before trying to insert I want to ensure that my parameters are valid. I can not find a way to check if a string(`com_create_guid()` returns string) is a valid GUID.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Considering a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) is defined as something like this : "A98C5A1E-A742-4808-96FA-6F409E799937" *(from what the wikipedia page says)*

I suppose using a regex like this one would do :

```
$guid = 'A98C5A1E-A742-4808-96FA-6F409E799937';
if (preg_match('/^\{?[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}\}?$/', $guid)) {
  var_dump('ok');
} else {
  var_dump('not ok');
}
```

It will match for

- 8 characters (both letters and numbers)
- 4 characters
- 4 characters
- 4 characters
- 12 characters

Each set of characters being separated by a '`-`'

Considering you're using [`com_create_guid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php), the regex check for optionnals `}` and `{` arround the guid, which means this would display 'ok' too :

```
$guid = '{A98C5A1E-A742-4808-96FA-6F409E799937}';
if (preg_match('/^\{?[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}\}?$/', $guid)) {
  var_dump('ok');
} else {
  var_dump('not ok');
}
```

Comment: The regex can be simplified:

[A-Z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Z0-9]{12}

Comment: it can be made shorter than what I proposed, indeed :-) But I think I'd still go with the "long" version, which is "simpler/quickier" to understand when you have to read it -- it won't change much, but as much as regex are a powerful tool, they are often hard to understand for those who don't know them well...

Comment: Aren't GUIDs hexadecimal? So why match on A-Z instead of A-F? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Only hex., optional {}'s, case insensitive:
  `/^\{?[a-f\d]{8}-(?:[a-f\d]{4}-){3}[a-f\d]{12}\}?$/i`

Comment: -'s are optional.

Answer (score 48):

There are a few rules that should be imposed on the UUID/GUID pattern.

- The only valid letters are a, b, c, d, e, and f.
- 0-9 can be replaced with the digit pattern \d
- GUIDs are often case insensitive.
- You either have {both brackets}, or none at all.

Simplified patterns

- hhhhhhhh-hhhh-hhhh-hhhh-hhhhhhhhhhhh
- {hhhhhhhh-hhhh-hhhh-hhhh-hhhhhhhhhhhh}

Expression:

```
var_dump(
preg_match("/^(\{)?[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){4}[a-f\d]{8}(?(1)\})$/i", $guid)
? "ok", "not ok");
```

Translation:

1. **/** beginning of expression
2. **^** beginning of string
3. **(\{)?** optional opening bracket {
4. **[a-f\d]{8}** 8 hex characters hhhhhhhh
5. **(-[a-f\d]{4})** 4 hex characters proceeded by dash -hhhh
6. **{4}** previous pattern repeated 4 times
7. **[a-f\d]{8}** 8 hex characters hhhhhhhh
8. **(?(1)\})** if first pattern was present {, then match closing tag }
9. **$** end of string
10. **/** close expression
11. **i** ignore case sensitivity

Comment: First para: "E" is missing :)

Comment: +Grouping error. It looks like the last group should be: `(?(1)\})` -> `(\})?`, or even `\}?` since it's a single character.

Comment: the -'s are optional.